# designing functions data definitions

Tags: scheme, racket

```
; A list-of-images is either   
; empty      
;    or       (cons n lon),
; where n is an image and lon is a list-of-images.
```

how would you develop a function `height-total` that consumes a list of images and returns the sum of all the images heights? i am confused. Could you use the function `image-height` for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution follows naturally as a recursive procedure; because this looks like homework I'll let you figure out the details, and of course you'll have to use the `image-height` procedure:

```
(define (height-total list-of-images)
  (if <???>                      ; if the list is empty
      <???>                      ; then what's the height sum of an empty list?
      (+ (image-height <???>)    ; else add the height of the first image and
         (height-total <???>)))) ; advance recursion to the rest of the list
```

Notice that the solution to this and many other problems over lists adheres to the same basic recursive structure, I'd recommend you take a good look at either [How to Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/) or [The Little Schemer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262560992) to better understand how to solve this kind of problems.

Comment: With a bit more of practice this problem can be easily solved using higher-order prcedures (`apply`, `fold`, `map`, etc.) but that's beyond the point for now, better understand the basics first.

Answer (score 0):

Using Racket:

```
(for/sum ([image image-list])
  (image-height image))
```

or

```
(foldl (lambda (image sum) (+ (image-height image) sum))
       0 image-list)
```

or

```
(apply + (map image-height image-list))
```